# Steam Link app network problems

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, streaming

I setup an Pi 3 (B+) for connecting to steam on my main computer. Steam Link is an application used for connecting remote devices (like the pi) as client with steam on the host computer (https://store.steampowered.com/steamlink/about/?l=english).

The name was also used for the hardware device from Valve which basically does the same. The main computer (called "Cronus") is connected via ethernet directly to the router. The Pi is connected via wifi (build-in wifi; 5G and no interferrers on the channels).
The Connection in Steam Link is basicly ok but **periodically lagging; ~6sec slow connection/high ping every ~30sec.**
If I connect the pi via ethernet everythign is fine....
The problem is: Since I dont want to place an 20m ethernet cable through 2 rooms and the corridor I need another solution.
I might try out an usb antenna soon.

**Q: Is the problem the build-in wifi chip or is it an general network issue? And How can I get a stable connection without the usage of a direct ethernet cable?**

Comment: What is "Steam Link"?

Comment: @Ingo Steam Link is an application used for connecting remote devices (like the pi) as client with steam on the host computer (https://store.steampowered.com/steamlink/about/?l=english). The name was also used for the hardware device from Valve which basically does the same

Comment: Please don't use comments for additional information. Instead edit the question. I have done it for you ;-)

Comment: @Ingo I will keep it in mind for my next questions :) Sadly there was no activity in this thread so i had to spend money and time by myself and posted the test results as answer. Feel free to edit the answer to improve the quality and/or readability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran multiple tests on diverent connection setups. Now i want to provide my results.

**My setup: high-end gaming pc/workstation (called "Cronus"; connected via Ethernet cat 7 directly to the router; living room); Raspberry Pi 3 B+(called "PiBox"; bedroom)**

**Goal: Get a stable connection via steam link app from "PiBox" to "Cronus".**

I used the following things to test the connection stability and the usability:

1. **WIFI (internal)**
2. **WIFI (USB-Antenna)**
3. **EoP (Ethernet-over-Power; used tplink powerline series adapter)**

> **Warning: The results depends on your walls, hardware, the cabling of your home, direction of the antenna and so on; There is and will never
>   be any guarantee that your setup works exactly as mine**

The results for the different setups are:

**1. WIFI (internal):** connection is basically good and pretty low ping, but there are periodically lags. These lags are too extreme for a fluid workflow. The screen is freezing for seconds...

**2. WIFI (USB-Antenna):** connection is less stable than internal wifi but by far more fluid for streamign the screen and inputs. Even if the connection is more susceptible to interference, the lags itself are less critical so we got a basic improvement. Still lags might occur from time to time but with shorter critical spikes (I defined the critical spikes around 150ms and up).
*My thougth was that if the problem is the internal wifi chip, I could avoid it by using usb. Looks like it works but the connection itself is not stable enough for my personal taste.*

**3. EoP:** A higher base latency compared to the other setups but a very stable connection with pretty high data transfer. *I personally would recommend this setup since its the best setup for wireless connections i had so far*

**Solution: I spend around 40$ for a stable and fluid connection (more or less wireless since there is no direct ethernet cable form PiBox to the router). The other solutions were cheaper but not stable enough**